# VB.Net Check for keyboard device

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, device

I've been looking around for a way to detect if I have a physical keyboard attached to my computer from vb.net but can't find anything. The problem is all googled results returned think what I mean is detecting a keyboard input (AKA: keystrokes). But I want to know if there is a physical keyboard attached. I have also looked into listing USB devices but realize that not all computers (take notebooks for instance) use USB keyboards.

How can I check if a keyboard is attached/operational from VB.net?

Comment: USB keyboards notify removal, but PS/2 Keyboards (that may also have a USB connection), do not. The Driver always returns `Status = OK`. You may want to detect whether the PC has Touch capabilities, if you need to show your OSK. I don't remember whether [GetRawInputDeviceList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdevicelist) has this same limitation. WMI for sure. Try it out.

Comment: Jimi your sugestion work great thanks :)

Comment: Jimi you wouldnt knw a way of temporaraly disableing a keyboard on a Windows 8 notebook for testing purposes by any chance...? I've run into a minor problem with another machine but only have my own notebook to test with

Comment: Do you mean like this: [BlockInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN)? Or do you want to disable the Keyboard Driver? As Device Manager->Keyboard->Replace with wrong Driver. Via BIOS? See also [Windows Device Console (Devcon.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) (you didn't really mention what kind of *block* you have in mind)